# In Rust, how to inspect values captured by a closure?

Tags: generics, rust, lambda, reflection, closures

In Rust, how can I create a function accpeting a closure as argument that iterates and prints all values captured by the closure reflectively?

For example:

```rust
fn print_captured_values<F>(f: F) where F: Fn() {
  // How to implement it?
}
```

Comment: You can't. There is no reflection in Rust.

Comment: look like xy problem

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

Closures have anonymous opaque types and only implement the `Fn*` traits (and auto traits) they can. Rust does not have reflection and it's reflection-like mechanisms aren't possible on non-local types.

Comment: But debuggers can, right?

Comment: @YangBo But not in any way directly accessible in the language. You might be able to use something like https://github.com/gimli-rs/gimli to access it in an implementation specific way on a specific platform, but its only ever best effort and has a tendency to break in optimized builds, unlike languages with built in reflection capabilities.